# Difference between inline generics and where clauses?

Tags: generics, rust

What is the difference generics and inline (I don't know what they are called) type definitions?

Example code:

```rust
fn main() {
    c(|| {
        println!("hello");
    })
}

fn a<F>(f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static,
{
    f();
}

fn b<F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static>(f: F) {
    f();
}

fn c(f: FnOnce() + Send + 'static) {
    f();
}
```

Here `a` and `b` works fine but `c` gives an error:
"trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword"

If I add the `dyn` keyword this time it gives another error: "the size for values of type `(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time"

So can you explain me how the type declaration in `c` is different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` and `b` are exactly equivalent. `c` *used* to be allowed (but meant something different), but they've added a keyword to disambiguate. The equivalent using the new syntax would be

```
fn c(f: impl FnOnce() + Send + 'static)
{
    f();
}
```

This is identical to `a` and `b` except that callers are not allowed to explicitly specify type annotations, so `a::<SomeType>(x)` is allowed but `c::<SomeType>(x)` is forbidden. This generally doesn't matter for `FnOnce` since the type is likely to be a lambda type anyway that's impossible to spell out.

The compiler suggestion to put `dyn` in changes the meaning.

```
fn c(f: &dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)
{
    f();
}
```

This does *not* declare a generic function. It declares a function taking a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html). In the generic function case, the type of the generic is known at compile time, which enables *much* better optimizations (often, `FnOnce` arguments which are lambdas can be inlined entirely). `dyn` is used when the type is *not* known at compile-time and more directly emulates Java-style `interface`s with implementation hiding.

(I also had to add a `&` since `dyn` types are unsized and cannot be function arguments. You could also put it in a `Box<dyn ...>` if ownership is required)

You should use generics instead of `dyn` whenever possible. Of the three implementations `a`, `b`, and `c`, they're all almost equivalent, save for being able to specify type arguments in the case of `a` and `b`. For `FnOnce` and company, I'd use `c` since we almost never want to specify arguments anyway. For other traits (`FromIterator` is a big one where we frequently want to specify the type), I would probably favor `a` or `b`; which of those two is up to your preference. Those two are entirely equivalent.